# eleventy: Netlify does not show Workflow tab

Tags: netlify, eleventy

I have cloned this eleventy : https://github.com/anborg/eleventy-netlify-boilerplate

I'm trying to enable netlify CMS with local git repo.

I expect to see Workflow section (between Contents and Media) in the below screenshot. What setting should I change to enable Workflow ?

http://localhost:3000/admin/#/collections/blog
[image]

admin\config.yml

```yaml
local_backend:
  url : http://localhost:3030/api/v1
  # when accessing this from other hosts
  allowed_hosts : ['*']

backend:
  name: github
  repo: anborg/one-click-hugo-cms
  branch: master # optional, defaults to master
  open_authoring: true

# Uncomment below to enable drafts
publish_mode: editorial_workflow
```

.env

```sh
# This file is used by stat:netlifyProxy for port 3030
#### below props are for npx netlify-cms-proxy-server #######

# optional, defaults to current directory
#GIT_REPO_DIRECTORY=FULL_PATH_TO_LOCAL_GIT_REPO
# optional, defaults to 8081
PORT=3030
```

package.json has proxy

```json
{
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3030",
  "name": "eleventy-netlify-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "A boilerplate for building a fast static website with the Eleventy static site generator, for deployment to Netlify.",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "run-p start:**",
    "start:eleventy": "set ELEVENTY_EXPERIMENTAL=true && npx @11ty/eleventy --serve --port=3000",
    "start:netlifyProxy": "npx netlify-cms-proxy-server",

    "build": "npx eleventy",
    "watch": "npx eleventy --watch",
    "debug": "DEBUG=* npx eleventy"
  },
  "repository": {
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isn't working because the `local_backend` section isn't set up correctly, or isn't supported by the editorial workflow yet.

According to the [docs](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/#publish-mode), you do have to use a supported Git service: GitLab, GitHub or BitBucket, as the editorial workflow is using the specific Pull-Request features of those services.

Try removing that bit from the config and the `editorial_workflow` will connect via the github gateway.

Comment: My requirement is "local backend" AND "editorial workflow".   i.e Setup a local CMS ui/workflow for internal users.  Looks like that is deliberately disabled -- so people are forced to go to netlify hosting.  If that is the case,  have to find some other javascript-cms :-).

Comment: You don't have to use netlify hosting, but you do have to use a supported Git service.
The CMS just makes git commits, so you want those to be up on github, not locally.

Comment: Are you able to setup  an intranet  cms  server  e.g http://mylocalcms:port/admin. i.e no "localhost" ?

Comment: Netlify CMS doesn't require a CMS server, it requires a Github or Bitbucket backend for the Editorial Workflow.